# Why does my python command for google search return a different number of links every time?

Tags: python, url, python-2.x

```
from googlesearch import search
Queries = ['a','b','c']
for Query in Queries:
    for url in search(Query, tld="com", num=10, stop=1, pause=2):
        print url
```

I thought that the param num determines the number of links I should receive, but I seem to get a different number every time I run this. Most of the times it's 10, but not always. Any explanations?

Comment: Is it always less when it's different?

Comment: Surprisingly, no :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the [only_standard](https://github.com/MarioVilas/googlesearch/issues/9#issuecomment-74321415) parameter to `True`? As per the issue I linked that appears to solve the problem for the user.

Also, remember that this module uses the Google Search Legacy API (as stated [here](https://github.com/MarioVilas/googlesearch/issues/9#issuecomment-74307901)), so results may vary from what you see when manually searching Google.